# Sharepoint API post gets access denied, permissions seem correct

Tags: sharepoint-api

I am tryin to post to sharepoint's api. I can read just find, just cant add items.
Here are my permissions.

[image]

When i post a new item in a list I get:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

What am i missing